# Groupby array of object multiple times

Tags: arrays, object, nested

considering the following data

```
let dataset =
    [
      {
        "Category": "Auto",
        "Parent": "Automotive",
        "name": "Auto - Multi Purpose Vehicles",
        "High": "10",
        "Low": "15",
        "Medium": "5"
      },
      {
        "Category": "Auto",
        "Parent": "Automotive",
        "name": "Auto - Off road",
        "High": "1",
        "Low": "2",
        "Medium": "3"
      },
      {
        "Category": "Auto",
        "Parent": "Ecology & Environment",
        "name": "Vegetarian",
        "High": "5",
        "Low": "5",
        "Medium": "10"
      },
      {
        "Category": "Home",
        "Parent": "Ecology & Environment",
        "name": "Weather",
        "High": "10",
        "Low": "15",
        "Medium": "5"
      }]
```

I want to group data in the following way

```
[{
  name: "Auto",
  data: [{
            name: "Automotive",
        data: [{
                name: "Auto - Multi Purpose Vehicles",
            value: 30
                High: 10,
                Low: 15,
                Medium: 5
            },
           {
                name: "Auto - Off road",
            value: 6
                High: 1,
                Low: 2,
                Medium: 3
          }]
        }, {
        name: 'Ecology & Environment',
        data: [{
          name: "Vegetarian",
           value: 20
               High: 5,
               Low: 5,
               Medium: 10
          }]
        }],
  name: "Home",
  data: [{
        name: "Ecology & Environment",
        data: [{
            name: "Weather",
            value: 30
            High: 10,
            Low: 15,
            Medium: 5
            }]
          }]

}]
```

What I've tried so far never land me to the desired output.

here is where I'm stacked.

```js
let cat = []
        
        dataset.forEach((d) => {
          const { Category, Parent, name, High, Medium, Low, value } = d;
          let category = cat.find((item) => item.Category === Category);
          let parent = cat.find((item) => item.data.Parent === Parent);
        
          if (!category) {
            cat.push({
              Category,
              data: []
            })
          } else if (!parent ) {
           
          cat.forEach(i => {
            i.data.push({
              Parent,
              High,
              Medium,
              Low
            })
          })
          }
        })
```

I've tried several ways with different results but I'm not able to figure out how to handle it
I'm not an expert in javascript. I'm trying to learn by doing but sometimes i get stack
Many thanks for any help
P.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the answer you want, follow this code.

**step 1:**
fire get the unique category from the dataset

**step 2:**
after getting a unique category, look for the particular category into a dataset, and when a category is found push it into the array

follow below code snippet

```js
let dataset = [
  {
    Category: "Auto",
    Parent: "Automotive",
    name: "Auto - Multi Purpose Vehicles",
    High: "10",
    Low: "15",
    Medium: "5",
  },
  {
    Category: "Auto",
    Parent: "Automotive",
    name: "Auto - Off road",
    High: "1",
    Low: "2",
    Medium: "3",
  },
  {
    Category: "Auto",
    Parent: "Ecology & Environment",
    name: "Vegetarian",
    High: "5",
    Low: "5",
    Medium: "10",
  },
  {
    Category: "Home",
    Parent: "Ecology & Environment",
    name: "Weather",
    High: "10",
    Low: "15",
    Medium: "5",
  },
];

/* map function help us to get non unique 
  categoty like => [ 'Auto', 'Auto', 'Auto', 'Home' ] 
  `New Set()` object gave us unique array then
  we create new array using spread oprator */
let uniqueCategory = [...new Set(dataset.map((data) => data.Category))];
let uniqueParent = [...new Set(dataset.map((data) => data.Parent))];

// create new array for storing final output
let cat = [];

// loop over unique category
uniqueCategory.forEach((Category) => {
  // create new object for perticular category
  let obj = {
    name: Category,
    data: [],
  };

  uniqueParent.forEach((parent) => {
    let isDataEmpty = true;
    let parentObj = {
      name: parent,
      data: [],
    };
    // loop over dataset
    dataset.map((data) => {
      /* if we fount category same as unique category we have
              to push that data into particular category object */
      if (data.Category === Category && data.Parent === parent) {
        // delete category ket/value from object
        isDataEmpty = false;
        delete data.Category;
        parentObj.data.push(data);
      }
    });
    if (!isDataEmpty) obj.data.push(parentObj);
  });
  cat.push(obj);
});

console.log(cat);
```

Comment: thanks for the replay, I'm studing your solution couse it works only at the first level while I need to nest also other two level more. Parent and name